# Why is my inherited class's transform always null?

Tags: unity, c#, gameobject

I have a class inherited to another class, and I can't get the transform on the inherited class.

Here's what i have and trying to do

```
Class A:Monobehavior{}

Class B:A{}

//somewhere else

A object = new B();
```

but right now, whenever I try to get the transform of object, either from a function in B or out here via `object.transform`, it will always return null.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because what you have is a lone Monobehavior in a void.

It's not on any GameObject and it's not in the Transform tree.

You need to create it right on a GameObject by using AddComponent:

```
A object = some_game_object.AddComponent<B>() as A;
```